# PDO connection to multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, singleton

I have PDO class below:

```
class DB {

        private $dbh;
        private $stmt;

        static $db_type;
        static $connections;

        public function __construct($db, $id="") {

             switch($db) {
                case "db1":
                      try{

                          $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ms".$id, 'root', '', array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true ));
                      }  catch(PDOException $e){
                          print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
                          die();
                      }
                break;
                case "db2":
                      try{
                          $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users", 'root', '', array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true ));
                      } catch(PDOException $e){
                          print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
                          die();
                      }
                break;
            }
            self::$db_type = $db;
        }

        static function init($db_type = ""){ 

            print_r(self::$connections);


            if(!isset(self::$connections[$db_type])){ 
                self::$connections[$db_type] = new self($db_type); 
            } 

            return self::$connections[$db_type];
        }

        public static function query($query) {

            self::$connections[self::$db_type]->stmt = self::$connections[self::$db_type]->dbh->prepare($query);
            return self::$connections[self::$db_type];
        }

        public function bind($pos, $value, $type = null) {

            if( is_null($type) ) {
                switch( true ) {
                    case is_int($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                        break;
                    case is_bool($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                        break;
                    case is_null($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                        break;
                    default:
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
            }

            self::$connections[self::$db_type]->stmt->bindValue($pos, $value, $type);
            return self::$connections[self::$db_type];
        }

        public function execute() {
            return self::$connections[self::$db_type]->stmt->execute();
        }
    }
```

Next I tried to:

```
$id = 1;
DB::init('db1', $id);
```

And this return me an error:

```
Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'ms'<br />
```

Why my DB name is ms during connection as it should be ms1? Thanks.

Comment: why do you have so much databases?

Comment: Your `DB::init()` method takes only one parameter. You must be calling the wrong method (shouldn't it be the constructor instead?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your init method's signature is:

```
 static function init($db_type = "")
```

That means it only accepts a single argument, while you're calling it like so:

```
DB::init('db1', $id);
```

This can't work. Also: you need to read up on `static`, persistent connections and injection vs singletons... your code is full of problems. For a start: *always* specify the access modifiers.
Your title suggests wanting to use mutliple connections, yet you're reassigning the `$db_type` property over and over (it's static, and so shared over all instances).
You're attempting to use the `Singleton` pattern, which is pointless in PHP anyway, but in your case even more so, since your constructor is public, still...

Only use statics if you have to, and even then: think carefully: most of the time, having to use static means having to admit a design fault.

The `query` method accepts but 1 argument: a string, and executes that query on the connection that was last established. You're unable to choose on which DB this query will run. If not dangerous, than this is, and I don't want to be an ass about it, but I can't put it any other way: **This is *Terrible* code**.

Please, do refactor this code, if I were to find myself having to use this class, I'd just create my own instance of `PDO` and use that. No matter how you look at it: you're significantly restricting the queries one can execute, but you can't deny my access to `PDO` itself...

Comment: Change it to static function init($db_type = "", $id=""){ 
      
   if(!isset(self::$connections[$db_type])){ 
    self::$connections[$db_type] = new self($db_type, $id); 
   } 
   
   return self::$connections[$db_type];
  }

Comment: @user889349: about a hunderd... sorry: paste this question [on codereview for detailed feedback](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/16133/elias-van-ootegem)

Comment: @user889349 your BIGGEST problem is enumerated databases which smells of some unusual and unreliable design

Comment: It's here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30689/pdo-class-for-multiple-databases